# How to stop visual-studio-code from appending "v2" to the path when adding generic docker registry

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-registry, jfrog-container-registry

I'm trying to add JFrog Container Registry from Visual Studio Code Insiders. The connection is successful but getting 404 error because"/v2/' is automatically appended to the url. How can I disable this?

Comment: I'm not sure why "v2" is causing the issue here as v2 is used in the docker path. Could you try to use the docker client to perform the docker login and docker pull to the JCR and then confirm if the docker client works? If so then take the same things with VS code

Comment: Docker client also could login but cannot push the image. I am running local MacPro docker environment. The documentation refers to generating proxy settings within the Artifactory repository but the repository only show configuration.

Comment: How is your Artifactory being accessed? Is it something like http://12.13.14.15:8082/ui? if so, are you trying to connect to the Docker client as "docker login 12.13.14.15:8082"? and if this is the correct way you perform the Docker login then is the pull happens as "docker pull 12.13.14.15:8082/mydocker/myimage:mytag"?

Comment: Docker client access is "docker login localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/" wherin username and password credentials works. Trying to "docker push localhost:8082/artifactory/my-repository/myimage:tag" fails to push the image. On vscode, after loggin, 404 is the landing brows page.

Comment: the push is failing because of artifactory context, try docker push "docker push localhost:8082/my-repository/myimage:tag" without Artifactory context. Also, refer to this JFrog wiki https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-WithoutaReverseProxy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My company uses JFrog Artifactory for storing docker artifacts and it is available in browser as

```
https://my.company.com/artifactory/
```

where the artifactory/ suffix is the so called subdomain.
The docker registry api however is available via

```
https://my.company.com/artifactory/api/docker/my-docker-repository-key/
```

once I used this address the extension started working as intended.

Comment: You can read more about it here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Docker+Registry

Answer (score 0):

The `/v2` is part of the container registry API, so if you get a 404 accessing that, you aren't connecting to that API. The container registry listens on a different port of the Artifactory server. You need to connect to a proxy that recognizes a different hostname or port for the registry server and sends requests to the appropriate Artifactory backend. See the [Artifactory setup guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry) for how to setup that reverse proxy.